# No class .db.model.FileDB entity with id 0 exists?

Tags: reactjs, spring

I have a REST API in Spring Boot with JPA and Spring Security ,I manage to upload a file and download it successfully but  when I try to delete an existing user object in my database by ID, I get the following error message:

```
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class model.FileDB entity with id 
undefined exists!
```

I am new to react / springboot and I cannot find the exact error please HELP.

fileDB MODEL

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "files")
public class FileDB {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;
```

FileController.java

```
@DeleteMapping("/files/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteFile(@PathVariable String id){

storageService.deleteFile(id);
return new ResponseEntity<>("file deleted", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

FileService.java

```
public void deleteFile(String id) {
 fileDBRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

******react

```
export default class UploadFiles extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.selectFiles = this.selectFiles.bind(this);
this.upload = this.upload.bind(this);
this.uploadFiles = this.uploadFiles.bind(this);


this.state = {
  selectedFiles: undefined,
  progressInfos: [],
  message: null,

  fileInfos:  [],
  files:[]
 };
 }

 componentDidMount() {

UploadService.getFiles().then((response) => {
  this.setState({
    fileInfos: response.data,
  });
 });
}

deleteFile=(fileId) =>{

axios.delete("http://localhost:8181/files/"+fileId)
.then(response => {
if(response.data !=null){

this.setState({
 files:this.state.files.filter(file  => file.id !== fileId)  
 });
 }
 });
  };

render()
{
//code
<Table bordered hover striped variant="dark" >

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th> List of Files </th>
                                
                                <th> Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                fileInfos &&
                                fileInfos.map((file, id) => 
                                    <tr key = {id}>
                                         <td> <a href={file.url}>{file.name}</a> </td>   
                                         
                                         <td>
                                         
                                             <ButtonGroup>
                                            
                                             <Button onClick={this.deleteFile.bind(this,id)}  
  size="sm" variant="outline-danger">
                                             <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} />
                                             </Button>
                                             {' '}
                                             <Button  size="sm" variant="outline-danger">
                                             <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEye} />
                                             </Button>
                                             </ButtonGroup>
                                         
                                         </td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
 }
```

Comment: Your java code it's ok, you should take a look the `fileId` that your are passing as argument in the `deleteFile` you are getting undefined  when you try to access `file.id` in the `onClick` event

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What do you offer me as a solution? by which value I can change the id in the onClick

Comment: I replaced onClick = {this.deleteFile.bind (this, file.id) with
onClick = {this.deleteFile.bind (this, id), and I get the same error with a small difference (No class entity with id 0 exists!)
instead of undefined I have 0 now .

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code APi it's working properly, i thin the problem is in your client side, if the response of `UploadService.getFiles()` is something like this:

```json
{
....
data:[
   {
       "id": "afd564",
       "name": "hello",
       "link": "this the link"
    }
]
....
}
```

```js
export default class UploadFiles extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.selectFiles = this.selectFiles.bind(this);
this.upload = this.upload.bind(this);
this.uploadFiles = this.uploadFiles.bind(this);


this.state = {
  selectedFiles: undefined,
  progressInfos: [],
  message: null,

  fileInfos:  [],
  files:[]
 };
 }

 componentDidMount() {

UploadService.getFiles().then((response) => {
  this.setState({
    fileInfos: response.data,
  });
 });
}

deleteFile=(fileId) =>{

axios.delete("http://localhost:8181/files/"+fileId)
.then(response => {
if(response.data !=null){

this.setState({
 files:this.state.files.filter(file  => file.id !== fileId)  
 });
 }
 });
  };

render()
{
//code
<Table bordered hover striped variant="dark" >

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th> List of Files </th>
                                
                                <th> Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                fileInfos &&
                                fileInfos.map((file, id) => 
                                    <tr key = {id}>
                                         <td> <a href={file.url}>{file.name}</a> </td>   
                                         
                                         <td>
                                         
                                             <ButtonGroup>
                                            
                                             <Button onClick={this.deleteFile.bind(this,file.id)}  
  size="sm" variant="outline-danger">
                                             <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} />
                                             </Button>
                                             {' '}
                                             <Button  size="sm" variant="outline-danger">
                                             <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEye} />
                                             </Button>
                                             </ButtonGroup>
                                         
                                         </td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you generalize your answer for my case I tested but it doesn't  work ...

Comment: I just updated more carefully your code. could you try?

Comment: Can you clarify for me what change you made to the code. I noticed you changed only [onClick = {this.deleteFile.
bind (this, id)}] that I modified earlier ,with [onClick = {this.deleteFile.bind (this, file.id)] but it will give an undefined error that I received the first time before modifying it.

Comment: Look earlier i was telling you to check fileInfos has the right structure because  the backend logic it's ok. You need to check what is the response that you are getting in `response.data` because is that response that is doing that your code doesn't work. when you put `fileInfos.map((file, id)....` that means that js iterate the file object and the id is the index or position in the array of object for that reason you are now receiving 0 error because you are clicking the first element. do a console.log(fileInfos) and check is not empty and the structure